# selecting a datarow that does not exist in dataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do this :

```
DataRow DefaultTemplateRow = dt.Select("TEMPLATE_ID=1").CopyToDataTable().Rows[0];
if (DefaultTemplateRow == null)
 {
    dt.Rows.Add(0, 1, "Default", "", "By total", "1", "1");
 }
```

in my case I'm not sure if `TEMPLATE_ID=1` exist or no in the dataTable if the datarow don't exit it throws an exception before moving to the next statement how can i avoid the thrown exception ? should i use try catch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ To DatTable/DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DataRow DefaultTemplateRow = 
                  dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<int>("TEMPLATE_ID") == 1);
```

This would return `null` in case, if ID is not found.

*(You may substitute the type in `Field` extension method to what you have in database.)*

Later you can have your code:

```
if (DefaultTemplateRow == null)
{
   dt.Rows.Add(0, 1, "Default", "", "By total", "1", "1");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dt.Select("TEMPLATE_ID=1")
```

Already returns an array of DataRows. So you can check if there are more than zero rows by this:

```
DataRow[] DefaultTemplateRow = dt.Select("TEMPLATE_ID=1");
if (DefaultTemplateRow.Length > 0)
...
```